# FIFO connected both sides in C

Tags: c, named-pipes

i have a program that create a fifo and open it only to read **(O_RDONLY)** let's call it *server.c*, and then i have a program called *client.c* that connects to the other side of the **fifo** to write **(O_WRONLY)**. Is there any way, in *server.c*, to known when a *client* open the fifo?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to tell. Use a Unix-domain socket if you need this.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @Barmar probably i can do it in other way, but i want to know how many clients open the fifo to create a linked list or an array with client's info(pid,...)

Comment: There's no direct way to get that info, either. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619150/get-pid-of-sending-pipe-process

Comment: Opening one end of a fifo will block until the other end is opened.

Comment: @Shawn i know, i wanted do know if is possible to know, after open one end, when the other end is open

Comment: You know when the `open()` returns.

Comment: And you know when the last client disconnects because the server's `read()` call returns 0, indicating EOF.  You then have to reopen the FIFO to detect when any other client connects.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but a open the pipe for clients in client.c and i open the pipe for server in server.c, i don't have the return value of open of client.c in server.c

Comment: Of course you don't have the client's file descriptor available in the server, but you don't need it.  The server's call to `open()` will return when the first client opens the FIFO for writing; other clients may also open the file for writing while at least one client has it open.  When all the clients disconnect (close the FIFO), then the server will get EOF on its file descriptor, and the server must then reopen the FIFO to get more data from any more clients.  That's the classic way it works; I believe that's mandated by POSIX.  There might be a platform that bends the rules, I suppose…